# How to dual boot windows 8 in ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-8

I'm currently running ubuntu 11.04 on my macbook and I would like to dual boot both ubuntu and windows 8. There are many tutorials on how to install ubuntu while runnung windows 8 but not the other way around. Could someone be kind enough to provide me a tutorial so I can install windows 8? Your help is very much appreciated. Please explain to me like I'm five.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new ntfs partition in which to install win 8, then if you start the installation from a bootable CD/DVD it should ask for the partition in which you want it installed. This goes in 2 steps, first you shrink you ubuntu partition, and then you create a new ntfs partition in the new free space. These two steps can be done from ubuntu with the tool 'gparted' which is in the repositories, is easy-to-use and well-documented.

Comment: I can't shrink my ubuntu partition because it's locked. It just won't let me change the size.

Comment: Right, since it is the partition you are on. Sorry, my fault. The easiest way then, I think, is to create an ubuntu bootable usb key and then use gparted from it.